# Trying to get Prometheus metrics from a file

Tags: docker, prometheus, monitoring

I'm currently attempting to set up GPU metric monitoring using Prometheus.

I have 2 servers, one running Debian, the other running Ubuntu. On the Debian server, I'm fetching data from nvidia-smi and storing it in a file.txt called metrics every 5 seconds. The data looks like this:

```
nvidia_gpu_utilization{index="0"} 0
nvidia_gpu_temperature{index="0"} 32
nvidia_gpu_memory_total{index="0"} 8192
nvidia_gpu_memory_used{index="0"} 1783
```

Additionally, the Ubuntu server pulls this file every 5 seconds (I couldn't use nvidia-smi-exporter for some reason).

On the Ubuntu server, I have Prometheus and Grafana running in Docker. I added the following block to the scrape_configs section:

```
- job_name: 'gpu_metrics'
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost']
  file_sd_configs:
    - files:
        - '/opt/prometheus_stack/prometheus/metrics.txt'
      refresh_interval: 5s
```

after restarting Prometheus, it fails to start and outputs a lengthy log with repeated lines like:

```
ts=2023-11-22T14:26:19.018Z caller=main.go:487 level=error msg="Error loading config (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml)" file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml err="parsing YAML file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: path name \"/opt/prometheus_stack/prometheus/metrics.txt\" is not valid for file discovery"
```

ChatGPT and Google haven't been helpful. Does anyone know a solution?